# Grunt is extremely slow - 100% cpu

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, typescript

I am trying to build AngularJS project with grunt (Ubuntu 14.04), but when running it eats 100% CPU is extremely slow.

Here is my grunfile

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-typescript');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compress');

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        typescript: {           
            home: {
                src: ['src/routes/home.ts'],
                dest: 'build/compiled_app/routes/home.js',
                options: {
                    ignoreTypeCheck: false
                }
            },
            controller_tests: {
                src: ['tests/unit/controller/*Test.ts'],
                dest: 'tests/build',
                options: {
                    ignoreTypeCheck: false
                }
            },
            services_tests: {
                src: ['tests/unit/services/*.ts'],
                dest: 'tests/build/ServicesTests.js',
                options: {
                    ignoreTypeCheck: false
                }
            },
            filters_tests: {
                src: ['tests/unit/filters/*.ts'],
                dest: 'tests/build/FiltersTests.js',
                options: {
                    ignoreTypeCheck: false
                }
            }
        },

        less: {
            options: {
                paths: ['src/less'],
                yuicompress: true,
                nospawn: true,
                livereload: true
            },
            compile: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'src/less',
                src: '**/*.less',
                dest: 'build/assets/css/',
                ext: '.css'
            }
        },

        copy: {
            assets: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/',
                src: ['**', '!root_content/**'],
                dest: 'build/assets'
            },
            root_content: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/root_content/',
                src: '**',
                dest: 'build/'
            },
            min_js: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'build/compiled_app/',
                src: ['**/*.js', '*.js'],
                dest: 'build/compiled_app/',
                ext: '.min.js'
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            options: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true
            },
            app_pages: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'pages/',
                src: ['**/*.html', '*.html'],
                dest: 'build/'
            },
            app_views: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'src/views',
                src: ['**/*.html', '*.html'],
                dest: 'build/compiled_app/views',
                filter: 'isFile'
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false
            },
            app: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'build/compiled_app/',
                src: '**/*.js',
                dest: 'build/compiled_app/',
                ext: '.min.js'
            }
        },

        karma: {
            unit: {
                basePath: '',
                frameworks: ['jasmine'],
                files: [
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-route.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-resource.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-cookies.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-ipcookie.min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-mocks.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/async.min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/underscore-min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'assets/javascripts/ng-infinite-scroll.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'assets/javascripts/ui-bootstrap-0.6.0.min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'assets/javascripts/angular-strap.min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'build/compiled_app/*.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'build/compiled_app/routes/*.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/build/**/*.js', included: true}
                ],
                preprocessors: { '**/tests/build/src/**/*.js': 'coverage' },
                reporters: ['progress', 'coverage', 'junit'],
                singleRun: true,
                browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
                coverageReporter: {
                    type: 'cobertura',
                    dir: 'tests/coverage/'
                },
                junitReporter: {
                    outputFile: 'tests/coverage/test-results.xml',
                    suite: ''
                }
            },
            e2e: {
                basePath: '',
                files: [
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-route.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-resource.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-cookies.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-ipcookie.min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/angular-mocks.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/async.min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/assets/javascripts/underscore-min.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'assets/javascripts/ng-infinite-scroll.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'build/compiled_app/*.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'build/compiled_app/routes/*.js', included: true},
                    {pattern: 'tests/e2e/*.js', included: true}
                ],
                autoWatch: false,
                browsers: ['Chrome'],
                frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],
                singleRun: true,                
                plugins: [
                    'karma-junit-reporter',
                    'karma-chrome-launcher',
                    'karma-firefox-launcher',
                    'karma-jasmine',
                    'karma-ng-scenario'
                ],
                junitReporter: {
                    outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
                    suite: 'e2e'
                }
            }
        },

        clean: {
            output: ['build/', 'tests/build', 'tests/coverage']
        },


        watch: {

            typescript: {
                files: ['src/**/*.ts'],
                tasks: ['package-js'],
                options: {
                    debounceDelay: 500
                }
            },
            // Watch task for html partials and main pages
            // It calles task to package html in correct folder
            html: {
                files: ['src/**/*.html', 'pages/**/*.html'],
                tasks: ['package-html'],
                options: {
                    debounceDelay: 500
                }
            },
            // Watch task for less files. Will execute task to compile
            // less files and package them in correct folder
            less: {
                files: ['src/**/*.less'],
                tasks: ['package-less'],
                options: {
                    debounceDelay: 500
                }
            }

        },

        compress: {
            main: {
                options: {
                    mode: 'tgz',
                    archive: 'build/landing.tar.gz'
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'build',
                src: ['**/*'],
                pretty: true
            }
        }

    });


    grunt.registerTask('package-js', ['typescript', 'copy:min_js']);
    grunt.registerTask('package-html', ['htmlmin']);
    grunt.registerTask('package-less', ['less']);

    grunt.registerTask('compile', ['less', 'typescript']);
    grunt.registerTask('app', ['compile', 'htmlmin:app_pages', 'htmlmin:app_views']);
    grunt.registerTask('assets', ['copy:assets', 'copy:root_content']);
    grunt.registerTask('package', ['app', 'assets', 'uglify:app']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'package']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['default', 'compress']);
    grunt.registerTask('test', ['clean', 'typescript', 'karma:unit']);
    grunt.registerTask('tests', ['test']);
    grunt.registerTask('dev', ['app', 'copy:min_js']);

};
```

I have been using the same for a while without any problem, and all was fine! It has started by a sudden and I tried several things to boosting it without any result. I assume it is not connected with the grunt itself, but more to the system which I am using (it's fine on other OS's). What can be a problem?

**UPDATE:**

After re-installing `grunt-contrib-uglify` everything seems to be fine. Still `uglify` task takes one minute to completed, but that more or less fine, considering the amount my modules to be compiled.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `time-grunt` to output data about which task is causing the problem. You can then focus your efforts on optimizing that particular task.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/time-grunt

*Disclosure: This is a boss library that I have nothing to do with.*

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot! Though the problem is that it is 50 / 50. Sometimes it is totally fine, sometimes it takes forever... ```time-grunt``` is very helpful anyway, thnx

Comment: @vtorosyan For future visitors could you update your question with your findings as to what was the slow subtask?

Comment: Be sure to checkout http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/10/05/grunt-performance.html which explains time-grunt.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to update all the packages. I work on the grunt-ts team and we have had file watching randomly giving us 100% cpu both with the watch library that karma uses and the one that grunt-watch uses

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of grunt modules then [jit-grunt](https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt) might help. It only loads the grunt modules required for the task you are running, rather than trying to load every single one each time.

You can see the implementation here with load-grunt-config here:

http://ia.njamieson.co.uk/2015/03/27/speeding-up-grunt-initial-load-jit-grunt-and-load-grunt-config/

Answer (score 0):

Add `interval` in `options`:

```
options: {
  interval: 5007,
  nospawn: true,
  livereload: true
}
```